# Apache Recompile effect on already installed SSL

Tags: apache, ssl

I have to recompile and install apache 2.4 to block server header in head request for a client but the client has recently purchased an SSL for about $400. Im not sure if the SSL can be used with a new version of apache if I recompile and install this on server.

Has anyone had any experience on this or any pointers that whether I can use existing SSL or will I be required to buy a new SSL for this client?

Comment: SSL certificates aren't compiled into the server in any way -- it's done purely by configuration -- so you're good to go.

Comment: Thank You Colin for your quick help on this. So all I need will be the CSR and CRT to set this up again?

Comment: Not even that: you can just recompile and try and restart the webserver using the new binaries -- there will be a few changes going from 2.2 to 2.4 but I don't think the SSL config has changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificates can be used across different versions of Apache -- even across different web servers such as nginx, and even for other programs entirely.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html for the current documentation on configuring SSL.

If you're upgrading from Apache 2.2 the configuration is probably identical.

A complete list of changes needed when upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4 can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html